# regex to catch text until a signal word occurs

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which catches a text until a signal word occurs. Until the signal word is not the first word my solution works fine. Since I'm using python with the regex module the code is

```
new_text = regex.sub("^(?>.*\s)*?(?=SIGNALWORD)", "", text)
```

And

```
blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla
SIGNALWORD blublub blublub
blublub blublub blublub
SIGNALWORD blabla blabla 
blabla blabla
```

becomes

```
SIGNALWORD blublub blublub
blublub blublub blublub
SIGNALWORD blabla blabla 
blabla blabla
```

But if the signal word is the first word it does not work properly. And

```
SIGNALWORD blublub blublub
blublub blublub blublub
SIGNALWORD blabla blabla 
blabla blabla
```

becomes

```
SIGNALWORD blabla blabla 
blabla blabla
```

I want it to do nothing if the signal word is the first word. I've played with the `regex.DOTALL` and `regex.MULTILINE` parameter, but I had no positive match.

Comment: So do you want to trim everything from your text until the signalword? Maybe use `\A` to assert position to be the start of the string in that case: [`\A.*?(?=\bSIGNALWORD)`](https://regex101.com/r/AvraIw/1)

Comment: Unfortunately the expression does not work.

Comment: Instead of replacing those before the signal word to null, why not just capture from the signal word onward ?   As simple as `SIGNALWORD.*` with `re.DOTALL` can already capture what you want in the 2 examples above.  Any other additional condition required ?

Comment: Use `regex.sub(r'^.*?(?=SIGNALWORD)', '',  text, flags=regex.S)`

Comment: Wiktor, sorry. That still leads to the same outcome I already got. The problem is that I want it to do nothing if the SIGNALWORD is the first word. And your solution cuts the text for this case, as mine does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead `(?!SIGNALWORD)` to assert that the string does not start with `SIGNALWORD`

```
import regex

text = ("blabla blabla blabla\n"
            "blabla blabla\n"
            "SIGNALWORD blublub blublub\n"
            "blublub blublub blublub\n"
            "SIGNALWORD blabla blabla \n"
            "blabla blabla")

new_text = regex.sub("^(?!SIGNALWORD)(?>.*\s)*?(?=SIGNALWORD)", "", text)
print(new_text)
```

See the outcome of the first [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourJLWiRMFWQUMpKScRiBRQqJg8JS4FJKCEXzbY093P0SfcP8gFqKIUhGA0FoNQ5HGqQzES2YH4naakycWVl1oeD/Ud2K96xaVJGkpxGvaKCEM1Nezt9LRiijW17DXsbZHElXQUlIAYpF@Tq6AoM69EA2ae5v//AA) and the second [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourJLWiRMFWQUMp2NPdz9En3D/IRcEwKacUhBSgdEyeEpcCElBCk8epDslMo6ScRCBSgFJYjESSVtLk4spLLY@HOg7sVL3i0iQNpTgNe0WEqZoa9nZ6WjHFmlr2Gva2SOJKOgpKQAzSr8lVUJSZV6IBM0/z/38A).

Comment: That is a nice solution. Thank you for the demo, too. @The fourth bird